# Google Colab taking too much time to train a classifier. How to fix this?

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, google-colaboratory

I want to train a classifier in google colab using Keras to classify if the image represents a dog or a cat. There are 8000 training samples and 2000 testing samples. The time taken for 1 epoch is 12hrs. I am new to google colab and i don't know how to fix this. I am using GPU as the hardware acceleration and i thought that having 1xTesla K80 would take less than 5 min but it is taking too much time.

I have tried changing the runtime to GPU as well as TPU but both the runtimes are not working.

Here's my code:

```
classifier = Sequential()

classifier.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), input_shape = (64, 64, 3), activation = 
 'relu'))

classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2)))

classifier.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation = 'relu'))
classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2)))

classifier.add(Flatten())

classifier.add(Dense(units = 128, activation = 'relu'))
classifier.add(Dense(units = 1, activation = 'sigmoid'))

classifier.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'binary_crossentropy', 
metrics = ['accuracy'])

from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255,
                               shear_range = 0.2,
                               zoom_range = 0.2,
                               horizontal_flip = True)

test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255)

training_set = train_datagen.flow_from_directory('/content/gdrive/My 
Drive/Colab Notebooks/dataset/training_set',
target_size = (64, 64),
batch_size = 32,
class_mode = 'binary')

test_set = test_datagen.flow_from_directory('/content/gdrive/My 
Drive/Colab Notebooks/dataset/test_set',
 target_size = (64, 64),                                          
batch_size = 32,
class_mode = 'binary')

classifier.fit_generator(training_set,
                     steps_per_epoch = 8000,
                     epochs = 1,
                     validation_data = test_set,
                     validation_steps = 2000)
```

There are many deprecations while executing this code. After executing classifier.fit_generator() , it shows 12 hrs remaining for 1 epoch

Comment: Does copying your data set from Drive to the local machine first help? (Often, incremental I/O from Drive is quite slow, and copying the dataset first to a local disk will help.)

Answer (score 4):

Check to make sure your using a GPU as sometimes even if I put the environment to GPU it still does not use it.

```
#' ' means CPU whereas '/device:G:0' means GPU
import tensorflow as tf
tf.test.gpu_device_name()
```

If that is good, then I would reset your runtime environment and try again. It should not take more than a few minutes to run. I did it with 10000+ photos before and it went through quickly ~ 6 min for each epoch. My images were much larger to 224,224 compared to 64,64

I have also found that using Kaggle kernels are a little quicker and does not have the issue of running into too large input sizes. I had to restrict Colab input for the training gen as it would run out of memory. Kaggle does not have this problem and it is much faster running through images. I think this is because they encode the images when you upload them to your dataset. They must convert them into numpy arrays from there as it goes much faster.

Comment: I did run the command to ensure that GPU is running still the time required is the same. I also tried running this code in Kaggle kernel and the time required is less than 15min. I don't understand this as both Kaggle and Colab offers the same GPU . Also I have Nvidia gtx 1050ti 4gb in my laptop which also needs more than 20 min for 1 epoch . The tesla k80 is far more superior than 1050ti so i guess it should need less than 5min for 1 epoch.

Comment: Yes you are right. It should not take that long. I will keep trying on my end to see if there is something odd that I can replicate

Comment: I recreated it a bit. The data was loading for a while and to fix it all I did was log off of Google completely and shut down chrome. I think somethings just get hung up on it.

Comment: I did find for the first iteration is a little slower than the rest as the data get loaded though the generator.

Comment: Thank you so much! I'll try running the code again . Thanks for your time

Comment: I also found out that if you are running too much stuff on your pc then Colabs will slow down and even stop mid process

Comment: Im am thinking that the slowness is related to the training generator. Once the first epoch goes through it speeds up significantly.

Answer (score 0):

try running by first coping your files locally

```
!cp '/content/gdrive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/dataset/training_set' 'training_set'
```

and then:

```
training_set = train_datagen.flow_from_directory('training_set',
target_size = (64, 64),
batch_size = 32,
class_mode = 'binary')

test_set = test_datagen.flow_from_directory('test_set',
 target_size = (64, 64),                                          
batch_size = 32,
class_mode = 'binary')
```

If coping is a slow process, upload to your drive a zipped file, copy this zip file to your colab and then unzip it.

Comment: getting this error while copying the files locally :                                                       
cp: -r not specified; omitting directory '/content/gdrive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/dataset/training_set